# slow queries were found in CMS JOOMLA and component DJ-CLASSIFIED

Tags: mysql, joomla

my website www.MultiBienes.com
is crashing

i use

VERSIONS:
Joomla 3.3.0
DJ-Classifieds 3.2.1
Template JM-JoomClassifieds 1.04

when i go to menu in administrator "Components / DJ-Classifieds / Items"
it never loads and show the error "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

and we identify
slow queries were found

sql1

*SELECT i.*, c.name as cat_name, u.name as user_name,a.c_abuse, i.date_start <= NOW() AND i.date_exp >= NOW() AS s_active, img.path as img_path, img.name as img_name, img.ext as img_ext, img.ordering as img_ord FROM ugzaw_djcf_items i LEFT JOIN ugzaw_djcf_categories c ON i.cat_id=c.id LEFT JOIN ugzaw_users u ON i.user_id=u.id LEFT JOIN ( SELECT count(a.id) as c_abuse, a.item_id FROM ugzaw_djcf_items_abuse a GROUP BY a.item_id ) a ON i.id=a.item_id LEFT JOIN ( SELECT img.id, img.item_id, img.name, img.path, img.ext, img.ordering FROM (SELECT * FROM ugzaw_djcf_images WHERE type='item' ORDER BY ordering) img GROUP BY img.item_id ) AS img ON img.item_id=i.id WHERE 1 order by i.id desc LIMIT 0, 20*

Comment: I suggest you contact the developer of DJ-Classified

Comment: i did but 2 days. no answer.  still wating.

Comment: Post an explain of the query. Then we can see if there are indexes in place at all relevant points

Comment: Do you have debug on? Also can you please format that so it is readable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This query was slow because of Joining images table, in current version it's changed and it works a lot of faster.